# RPMs and patching

Tags: rpm, diff, patch

I have 3 files (from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kernelloader/files/Sony%20Linux%20Toolkit/Package%20Update%20Files/binutils/))that I have been given to install in an attempt to upgrade the compiler:

> binutils-2.13.2.1-1.mipsel.rpm
>   binutils-2.13.2.1-1.src.rpm
>   binutils-2.13.2.1-r5900-7.diff.gz

I'm kinda fumbling around with this.

What I've done is:

```
rpm -i mipsel -vv
rpm -i src -vv
```

I have no idea what to do with the `.diff.gz` I understand it's a patch but don't really know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

Change to the toplevel source directory (the one containing the files `COPYING`, `bfd` and so on) and apply the patch:

```
zcat ../binutils-2.13.2.1-r5900-7.diff.gz | patch -p1
```

You almost always need to pass either `-p0` or `-p1` when applying a patch. The number is the number of path components to strip from the file names in the patch. Check the first few lines of the patch. Here, they are

```
diff -urN binutils-2.13.2.1.orig/ChangeLog.PS2 binutils-2.13.2.1/ChangeLog.PS2
--- binutils-2.13.2.1.orig/ChangeLog.PS2        1969-12-31 18:00:00.000000000 -0
+++ binutils-2.13.2.1/ChangeLog.PS2     2003-01-20 17:48:29.000000000 -0600
```

Since all paths have a leading directory, you need to pass `-p1`. If the first line was something like `diff -urN ../binutils-2.13.2.1.orig/ChangeLog.PS2 ChangeLog.PS2` or `diff -urN ChangeLog.PS2.orig ChangeLog.PS2`, you would use `-p0`.

Once you've applied the patch, run `rpmbuild -bb` to build a new binary package.

Comment: ah thanks, sorry my linux is not so hot, I dont really have a source directory. I assume I have to somehow unpack the .src.rpm

Comment: @PhilCK Ah, yes, my rpm is a bit rusty. I think that's `rpmbuild -bp /usr/src/rpm/SPECS/binutils-2.13.2.1-1.spec`, and the source will be unpacked in `/usr/src/rpm/SOURCES/binutils-2.13.2.1-1`.